# Odd resistor design

Tags: resistors, physical-design

In one of my designs, I specified the [Rohm LTR10EZPF1003 100K 0802-Wide](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rohm-semiconductor/LTR10EZPF1003/RHM1206CT-ND/4055423) resistor:

[image]

The issue is that when I added the resistor to the circuit, it creates a direct short:

[image]

- Measuring between the Green points is "No Connection" (expected 100K)
- Measuring between the Blue points is a short (expected 100K)
- Measuring between the Red points gives 100K ohms resistance. (expected NC)

Now I have no doubt that this is "by design" (the long white area's in the dimensional drawing are metallic plates), but what I can't figure out is what, in the [LTR Series Datasheet](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/datasheet/LTR100JZPD/ltr-e) would tell me about this behavior? The resistor land pattern is not any different from a normal 0802 component pad layout.

So, how can I identify this odd type of resistor and avoid its use? What should I be looking for in the specifications or data sheet?

Comment: I'm not convinced the land pattern is the same as the normal 802 pattern. It may look the same in their image, but when you draw it to scale using the dimensions given it looks quite different. If you don't want to use them.. don't pick 0802-WIDE devices.

Comment: Your expectations are for a normal SMD resistor, that have the connections on the short sides. These resistors have the connections on the _long_ sides (presumably for high current capability and/or low ESL - update: ah, the datasheet mentions joint reliability). This feature is probably the entire reason of existence for this series; if you want regular resistors, order regular resistors ;)

Comment: "Wide terminal type", "long side terminations"

Comment: The first line under "Features" on the datasheet says "High joint reliability with long side terminations".

Comment: Not to mention, it's clear in both pictures. The picture on the left clearly shows the pads going all the way across the top and bottom, with measurements showing the width of the contact areas. The picture on the right clearly shows the contact aras end one, one wrapped around the top and one wrapped around the bottom, and it's clearly depicting the small ends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how can I identify this odd type of resistor

By **reading the datasheet**, of course.

The datasheet is quite clear about where the connections are on this series of resistors.  In fact, it's featured.  There is no mystery here.  Your own measurements show that the part is working just like the datasheet says it is supposed to.

How to avoid this in the future?  **Read the datasheet *before*** specifying the part in a design.  That *really* should have been obvious.

Comment: "WIDE" resistors are exactly that -- their terminals are on the "wide" side (instead of the narrow side as @RonBeyer is expecting). Ron, try the [Vishay RCS0805100KFKEA](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/RCS0805100KFKEA/541-2850-1-ND/5867143) instead?

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to see where you went wrong.  Their data sheet is a little misleading.

I'd argue it is not all that clear from the datasheet since they use W in the image you post and C in the land pattern image, which is rotated.  But the title is: *High power chip resistors < Wide terminal type >*.  I'd read the *Wide terminal type* as a disclaimer as I read the datasheet.

From [Rohm LTR series data sheet](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/datasheet/LTR100JZPD/ltr-e):

[image: Wide land :]

Which would've been better represented as:

[image: Wide land pattern]

from [Panasonic Surface Mount Resistors Land Pattern](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AOC0000/AOC0000COL4.pdf).

Comment: Or alternatively just make the proportions in the picture match the actual part rather than a generic part (but keep the same pads-to-the-side orientation).

Comment: Some graphics artist did not do their job.

Comment: Reasonable approaches would have been to use a graphic generator which produces scaled pictures, have a stock diagram which illustrates both cases (uses more "paper" but would establish that e.g. "A" is always the dimension perpendicular to a line connecting the pad centers and "B" is always parallel), use two "stock" diagrams showing those two cases and insert whichever is appropriate for a given part, or add jagged "omission" markers on the sides of the pads (making clear they could be longer than shown).

Answer (score 4):

> how can I identify this odd type of resistor and avoid its use?

Use the "package / case" parametric filter on Digi-Key (where you linked) or other distributor websites so that only 0805 (not 0805 Wide) are selected.

https://www.digikey.com/short/300t5v

The 0805 Wide resistors are actually 0508 (the 08 and 05 flipped around) because the terminals are on the opposite side of the package (the long side) as is traditional (the short side).  They offer certain advantages in certain applications (lower inductance, better power handling for same board area, etc.), but are more expensive.